# What is the difference between a function and a map?

Tags: functions, terminology, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between mapping and function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function)

I am an aspiring mathematician who just started out. What is the difference between a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Definition) and a map? Or are these notions equivalent?

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function). It is identical.

Comment: I doubt there is even a precise definition of a function, because any definition has a counterexample.

Comment: @glebovg, "function" has a precise definition: A function from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is a subset $f$ of $A \times B$ such that for any $a \in A$ there exists a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. In this notation, you would denote $b$ by $f(a)$ and the point is that a function is completely determined by its graph.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the two have always been interchangeable. Occasionally one is chosen for emphasis. For instance, sometimes one will use the term "function" to refer specifically to a map of sets with no structure, rather than a continuous map of topological spaces or a homomorphisms of some algebraic objects. Alternatively, the term "map" is sometimes reserved for geometric kinds of things (spaces, manifolds, etc.).