# Name of a sequence that repeatedly applies the same function

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Let $A,B$ be some sets with $A\supseteq B$, let $a\in A$ be some element and let $f:A\to B$ be some map. Let the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be defined by $a_0 := a$ and $a_n:= f\left(a_{n-1}\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I would like give $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ a name, something like "the [...] sequence of $f$ with starting value $a$", and I was wondering if such name already exsits in the literature.

Comment: "The sequence of iterates of $f$ beginning at $a$" would be widely understood and fairly common. Different writers may vary...

Comment: I've seen _orbit_ used this way.

Comment: @kimchilover In my opinion orbit conveys the idea of the (unordered) set of values than the *sequence* of iterates.

Comment: @coffeemath The second paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(dynamics) says something slightly different.

Comment: @coffeemath: FYI, I've almost always seen "orbit" used in the sense of a sequence, at least in iteration theory. See [these papers](https://zbmath.org/?au=&ti=orbits), for example. Also, maybe [this MSE question is relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832571/13130).

Comment: @kimchi lover: FYI, I've almost always seen "orbit" used in the sense of a sequence, at least in iteration theory. See [these papers](https://zbmath.org/?au=&ti=orbits), for example.  Also, maybe [this MSE question is relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832571/13130). [same comment twice because the software limits me to alerting only one username]

Comment: To all. I'd retract my orbit remarks if it would not leave other comments unexplined.

Comment: @coffeemath: Actually, the MSE question I linked to indicates (in comment(s), answer(s), ...) that an unordered set of values is sometimes meant by "orbit", or at least I thought was the case (I don't remember now). Anyway, dynamical systems stuff is not something I know much about, but some aspects of it overlap with my interests and with mathematicians whose work I'm familiar with (e.g. [these google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterated+functions+%22Bruckner%22+%22Steele%22+%22orbit%22&filter=0)) and for those aspects "orbits" are sequences.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I had been thinking of the orbit-stabilizer theorem of group actions, in which unless the acting group has an order it doesn't see like orbits are ordered. Anyway I see now "orbit" is used in several ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ ist called [the orbit of $a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Abelian_property_and_iteration_sequences).