# Necessity of being well-defined in Group Homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

In Group Theory, homomorphism is isomorphism when we no longer restrict to bijective map; do we still need that map to be well defined in homomorphism (like in isomorphism) or homomorphism can be without requirement of "well-defined"?

P.S. We say that $\varphi$ is well-defined if $g=h$ implies that $\varphi(g)=\varphi(h)$.

Comment: Yes, it still must be a well defined function (and it must respect the group structure, so $\varphi(g_1g_2) = \varphi(g_1) \varphi(g_2)$.

Comment: You mean homomorphism, not homeomorphism. They are different things. The latter is from topology. You are putting way too much stock into the phrase "well-defined." There are no ill-defined maps, ever, period - only bona fide functions vs. failed attempts to define a function that didn't work out.

Comment: @anon - I haven't noticed for a long long time that it's homomorphism in group theory and hom**e**omorphism in topology! Thanks

Comment: Group homomorphisms are defined as functions from a group to another that preserve the operation; the fact that the word "function" is used in the definition tells you that homomorphisms are well-defined (relations that are not well-defined are not functions).

Comment: @coldnumber - the reason that I asked the question (OP) is that the book didn't use word "function" instead it says "map". (Abstract Algebra 
 by Thomas W. Judson)

Comment: @Edi: I see; you might be interested in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function

Comment: What would $f(42)$ be if we must be prepared to have $f(42)\ne f(42)$?

Comment: In reality, I would guess that many mathematics lecturers write things like "Define $f:G/N \to H$ by $f(gN) = h(g)$" (assuming that $h:G \to N$ is already defined), and then they say "First we must prove that $f$ is well-defined". Formally speaking this is wrong, because they haven't actually defined $f$ at all until they have proved it is well-defined, and it can sometimes be confusing to students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions, by their *definition* are well-defined: if one has a relation $f \in A \times B$, it is a function if and only if whenever $(a,b),(a,b') \in f$ we have $b = b'$. This allows to write (unambiguously) $b = f(a)$.

So functions can be:

1) One-to-one (these functions are called *injective*).

2) Many-to-one (for example, constant functions from a domain with more than one element).

Functions *cannot* be:

3) One-to-many. An image of a domain element must be a singleton.

However, with group homomorphsims, we often have homomorphisms defined on quotient groups (which are certain *equivalence classes* of a group).

Here is an example of something which is *not* well-defined: suppose we try to define-

$f: \Bbb Z_6 \to \Bbb Z$ by:

$f([a]_6) = a$. (Here, $[a]_6$ is the equivalence class of $a$ modulo $6$, where the equivalence is defined by:

$a\sim b \iff a-b$ is a multiple of $6$).

Note that $[3]_6 = [9]_6$, since $9-3 = 6$. But $f([3]_6) = 3 \neq 9 = f([9]_6)$.

We no longer have a unique image for $[a]_6$, it is not well-defined.

So when we define a function on a set of equivalence classes using elements contained in those equivalence classes, we need to be sure our choice of image is *independent* of the particular "representative" (element of the equivalence class) we calculate the image from. Another way of saying this, is that $f$ needs to be constant on each equivalence class, to induce a function on the equivalence classes.

Perhaps you have "well-defined" confused with *injective*, they *look* similar:

$f$ is injective if $f(a) = f(a') \implies a = a'$

Homomorphisms, unlike isomorphisms, are not required to be injective, isomorphisms must be (they must be *surjective*, or onto, as well). In fact, much of what is *interesting* about group theory comes from the fact that often, group homomorphisms are *not* injective, which leads to questions on "how much of the original group structure is preserved".