# Maps between topological spaces; any rules?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So I understand that for a "continuous" map between topological spaces, the pre-image of an open subset is an open subset. (There is no 'inverse map' unless the function is bijective, so careful there)

But in general...when one just says "map" between $X$ and $Y$, (though sometimes it's implicitly intended that it is continuous, in cases otherwise), is there a rule?

Like say, a map $\phi:X \to Y$ always maps an open element to an open element? I ask this because for a "continuous" map, the "inverse" is forced to map an open element from $Y$ to an open element of $X$. But nothing is said about $\phi$ itself. Does $\phi$ have to map an open element from $X$ to an open element of $Y$?

Or is this automatic if the inverse maps an open element to an open element? It seems so to me, but not very sure...though, being an "inverse" it logically makes sense I think that the statement is implied.

But I wish to have some clarification(I don't want to assume things and go on and realise I had a logic hole somewhere later)

...Actually, when we "map" topological space to another, are we mapping "sets"? Regardless of their size(cardinality)? So say, if $X=\{0,1\}$ and the topology $\tau=\{\phi,X,\{0\}\}$ is together a topological space $X$, and $Y=\{0\}$, then can I map $\{0,1\} \to \{0\}$? The former has cardinality $2$ and the latter $1$ but does this not matter? I'm confused since the "map" is slightly different from conventional "functions" that map elements to elements...I guess $\{0\}$ is not an "element" but a singleton "set" in a topological context?

Comment: Wait, what is an "open element" ? If you mean an open subset, then maps that do take an open subset to an open subset are called "open maps". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps

Comment: Actually, let me update my question since that confuses me haha

Comment: Map is usually a synonym for function. Anything can be a member of a set, including another set. Member is a synonym for element. A map $f:X \to Y $("from$ X$ to $Y$") is any $ f\subset \{(p,q):p\in X\land q\in Y\}$ such that for each $p\in X$ there is exactly one $q\in Y$ such that $(p,q)\in f.$ When $(p,q)\in f$ we write $q=f(p).$ Note that this defines a function as being equal to "its graph."  (Well, how else would you define it?)

Comment: if you find DanielWainfleet's comment interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function

Answer (score 0):

**1)** For starters, a map between metric spaces, $f:X\to Y$, is continuous if and only if the pre-image $f^{-1}(V)$ of any open subset $V\subset Y$ is itself an open subset of $X$.

Since it suffices to check this for balls, taking $V=B(f(x_0),\epsilon)$ we obtain that the ($\epsilon-\delta$) criterion for $f$ around $x_0$ is equivalent to $f^{-1}(V)$ containing a ball centred at $x_0.$

**2)** The way textbooks are organised generally follows the tidy structure first laid out by the Bourbaki group.  That is to say, when we are in the category (=context, for now) of differentiable manifolds, we assume that a map between such manifolds is differentiable; when the background is that of topological spaces, maps are continuous -- or else you are ignoring the topology, and simply stripping the spaces of it and merely viewing as sets!

**3)**  You are making reference to $f$(open subset) possibly being open, but this is a different condition.  It suffices to consider, say, the following function $$f:X\to X\times \mathbb{R},$$
defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$.  All open sets on $X\times \mathbb{R}$ are unions of products $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so obviously there is no open subset of $X$ whose image is open in the target space.

Comment: Hi, I'm baffled with small questions like, in topological spaces, does some map $\phi$(empty set) to another empty set? Or some subset to an empty set?

Comment: A topological space is a set plus extra structure, therefore maps of topological spaces, i.e. continuous maps, are maps of sets, and the image of the empty set is empty (just imagine an empty diagram).

Comment: You may enjoy this e-book
http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A map does not have to map open sets to open sets.

One example is the continuous constant maps $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

It maps open sets to closed sets.