# What is the difference between linear mappings and linear functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $V'$ be vector spaces over a field $K$. A [**linear mapping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) $$f:V \to V'$$ is a mapping which preserves addition and scalar multiplication.

My question is: what is the difference between linear mappings and linear functions?

Comment: None. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'd suppose a linear function takes values in $\mathbf R$ – in which case it would be better known as `linear form`.

Comment: When I was in school, a linear function was just a line, i.e., $f(x) = ax+b$. In general, a function usually maps to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, whereas a map or mapping can map to anything.

Comment: For some people, none. But for example $ax+by+c$ is traditionally called a linear function, though if $c\ne 0$ it should more precisely be called affine.

Comment: Relevant, almost dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function

Comment: Lang's *Linear Algebra* book says ''*A function is a special type of mapping, namely it is a mapping from a set into the set of numbers, i.e. into $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$, or into a field K.*''

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the definition you are using. Linear mappings are typically the same as linear functions, although in some contexts, a linear function is strictly some function in the form of $y = mx+b$.

Linear mappings are functions that map two domains and whose operations have linearity, that is the linearity of scalar multiplication and addition.

Answer (score -1):

For the **definition of linearity** it still the same for **functions or mappings**.

But the term mapping has more general uses than than function, a mapping could be a function, functional or operator...

However, these three terms are not the same.
 **A function** is a term you used for mappings that map a set A to B where A and B are subsets of real of complex numbers or almost any map into $R^n$ or $C^n$ .
 **A functional** is a mapping that is defined from a subset of a space X into the space of real or complex numbers.
 Finally **an operator** is defined from a space X to a space Y, where X, Y could sequence or function spaces.

Here an examples that clearfy more the difference between these three terms, 
let the function $f:R \rightarrow R $ such that  $f(x)= x$.

Let us integral this function between $0$ and $1$,  then $ \int^{1}_{0}x =\frac{1}{2}$.

You can notice that the defined integral is a functional, it mapped a function ( x ) into a real ( 1/2).

However the undefined integral of this function is a function,  $\int x =\frac{1}{2}x^2$.

Thus, the undefined integral is an operator.

**You can use the term of mapping for all previous examples but the term function can be uses only for the first case.**

Comment: How are those two last not functions?

Comment: Roughly speaking functions map points to points, Functionals map vectors to points and operators maps vectors to vectors

Comment: None of those are meaningful distinctions.

Comment: If you go with the somewhat naive definition that a function is something that takes an input and gives an output, functionals and operators do exactly that. If you take the better definition that a function is a certain special kind of relation, then functionals and operators are exactly that. I'm afraid that this answer is nonsense.

Comment: Not just an input but a point, that has no directions and no movements however the others do that is what I meant when I used the term vector A function maps a real to a real (or complex), functional maps a set from function space or sequence space to a real (or complex). However, the operators is from a sequence or fonction space to sequence or fonction space

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95741/is-there-any-difference-between-mapping-and-function and you can see that almost the answers agree with my response